# Help with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the test string:

```
<div class="comment-quoter">Comment by <strong>Tom</strong>
```

I want to change it to

```
[quote=Tom]
```

I've got as far as this but it gets no matches:

```
PostTxt = PostTxt.replace(new RegExp("<div class=\"comment-quoter\">Comment by <strong>{(.+),}</strong>", "g"), '[quote=$1]')
```

Comment: Not sure if it's recommended to do it in this manner at all; it is totally inflexible. Imagine if there are some markup changes because of some other javascript code, or extra whitespace would throw off the regex, etc.

Comment: @Davin, it's part of a comments system, it's tricky because people enter `[quote]rgrg[/quote]`, submit it, it's parsed as HTML, then when I edit the comments I need to reverse it to display in original format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
PostTxt = PostTxt.replace(new RegExp("<div class=\"comment-quoter\">Comment by <strong>(.+)</strong>", "g"), '[quote=$1]')
```

The round brackets denote the `$1` capture group, so the curly brackets and comma would match literals and aren't necessary.

Dependent on what you're expecting, you can make it less greedy by being more specific about the characters you're matching for the capture group:

`(\w+)`

would match one or more alpha-numeric characters and would return correct matches if you have more than one quote in your input string.

Comment: This doesn't match either sorry

Comment: Remember regular expressions are greedy. Yours *eats* too much and would fail when `PostTxt` contains more than one *quote*.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: Good stuff! I was beginning to question my sanity! :D

Comment: @Jason thanks, the system guarantees there will be no nested quotes though.

Comment: @Jason McCreary: I've added an update to denote that fact, cheers.

Comment: @Tom: It's not just about nested quotes, but about multiple quotes in one post (or whatever you're matching on). Just put a `?` after the `.+` and you'll fix the issue.

Comment: @Town, a quick question, I want to strip away any newlines after `</strong>`, IE, match `</strong>[\s\S]`, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without the overhead of explicitly creating a new RegExp object (since you're not storing it anyway) just do this:

```
PostTxt = PostTxt.replace(/<div class="comment-quoter">Comment by <strong>(.+)<\/strong>/g, '[quote=$1]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PostTxt = PostTxt.replace(/<div class="comment-quoter">Comment by <strong>(.+?)<\/strong>/g, '[quote=$1]')
```